# React: Pass Functions in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to add a function that returns a string depending on the value passed into the `config` function. Then, I want the returned string to concatenate to the existing objects listed in the `jsonFormat`. However,`typeDetails:` does not trigger the function, but it simply writes out the function as a string. How do I display the returned values from the config function?

```
const config = (value) => {
  let states = "";
  if (value === "A") {
    states = {
      a: {
        a1: 1234,
        a2: 4567,
      },
    };
  } else if (value === "B") {
    states = {
      b: {
        b1: 54321,
      },
    };
  } else {
    states = "";
  }
  return states;
};

var jsonFormat = {
  name: "May",
  type: "A",
  typeDetails: (type) => { // <- Where I am calling the config function
    config();
  },
};
return { jsonFormat }
```

Essentially, I want the jsonFormat to spit out like this as the end result. Thanks

```
  name: "May",
  type: "A",
  typeDetails:           
     a: {
        a1: 1234,
        a2: 4567,
     },
  };
```

Comment: You need to actually call the function: `typeDetails: config("A")`

Comment: @ChrisG It worked! How do I add more values to the `typeDetails` object? I've tried to approach with this solution: `typeDetails: config("A"), {name: value}`, but it's rendering as [object][object].

Comment: It's rendering that way because by default, any object is rendered as `[object Object]` (because that's what the default string conversion returns). This is independent of adding more stuff to `typeDetails` though, which you can do like this: `typeDetails: {...config("A"), name: value}`. You need to either insert a specific child like `<p>{data.jsonFormat.typeDetails.states.a.a1}</p>` or use something like `<pre>{JSON.stringify(someObject, null, 2)}</pre>` depending on what your goal is.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your swift response, and it worked wonders
!